# Epson DS530II scanner not detected by sane

Tags: scanner, compatibility, epson, sane

I have an EPSON DS530II scanner.
Output of lsusb:
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 04b8:0182 Seiko Epson Corp. DS-530II

output of sane-find-scanner:
found USB scanner (vendor=0x04b8 [EPSON], product=0x0182 [DS-530II]) at libusb:004:002

output of scanimage -L:
No scanners were identified. If you were expecting something different,
check that the scanner is plugged in, turned on and detected by the
sane-find-scanner tool (if appropriate). Please read the documentation
which came with this software (README, FAQ, manpages).

I added in /etc/sane.d:
usb 0x04b8 0x0182

I also added /etc/udev/rules.d/40-libsane.rules:
ATTRS{idVendor}=="04b8", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0182", ENV{libsane_matched}="yes"

But neither helped.
Has anybody any idea?

Ralf

Comment: Hello. What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: I already wrote that in my answer. I used 20.04 and upgraded to 22.04 (development). 20.04 uses old sane backends.

Comment: Install drivers from https://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/?OSC=LX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved: ubuntu 20.04 uses sane.backends 1.0.29. This scanner is supoorted only with backends 1.1.1. Ubuntu 22.04 uses backends 1.1.1. scanner works.